# Proving that the Lagrangian is time translation invariant

Tags: analysis, differential, euler-lagrange-equation

I know that the context is Physics, but my problem actually is related to Math:

In my textbook, the author deduce the expression of the lagrangian $L(q_i(t), \dot q_i(t), t )$ of a free particle only using classical physical symmetries where the $q_i(t)$ are independent coordinates and the $\dot q_i(t)$ their derivatives by time. 
To simplify let's just pretend $q_i(t) = x(t)$, and the lagrangian becomes $L(x(t), \dot x(t), t)$.

The proof begins with explaining that "the homogeneity of space and time implies that the Lagrangian cannot contain explicitly either $x(t)$  or the time $t$". I would like the mathematical proof of this statement but I am struggling with the time translation invariance: I would like to prove that $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial t} = 0$.

Let $t'$ be the image of $t$ by a translation $t' = t + dt$ with $dt$ an infinitesimal time duration. This should induce $x$ and $\dot x$ variations:

$$
 L(x(t'), \dot x(t'), t') = L(x(t) + \delta x, \dot x(t) + \delta \dot x, t + d\tau)
$$

Because lagrangian is time translation invariant, $L(x(t'), \dot x(t'), t') = L(x(t), \dot x(t), t) \quad (*)$.

Using first order Taylor's expansion:
$$ 
 L(x(t'), \dot x(t'), t') = L(x(t), \dot x(t), t) + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial x}\delta x + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\delta \dot x + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial t} dt + \mathcal{o}(\lvert\lvert (\delta x, \delta \dot x, dt)\rvert\rvert)
$$

by neglecting higher order terms, $(*)$ becomes :

$$
L(x(t), \dot x(t), t) + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial x}\delta x + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\delta \dot x + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial t} dt  = L(x(t), \dot x(t), t)
$$
$$
\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial x}\delta x + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\delta \dot x + \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial t} dt  = 0
$$

and I don't know how to conclude that $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial t} = 0$.

Comment: The term proportional to $\delta t$ should be $\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} \delta t$. Integrate by parts the term proportional to $\delta \dot{x}$.

Comment: yes, sorry it is a copied/pasted error. So if I integrate by part the term I get $ \int \dfrac{\partial L }{\partial \dot x}\delta \dot xdt = \left[  \dfrac{\partial L }{\partial \dot x}\delta x \right] - \int \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\delta x dt$, so the last equation becomes $\int \left( \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial x} - \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\right)\delta x  dt + \int \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial t}dt = 0$ and the first integral equals to 0 because of the Euler Lagrange Equation, that's it ?

Comment: Right. In practice, you don't need to integrate, basically you can just use the product rule as in $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta \dot{x} = \frac{d}{d t} \left[ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta x \right] - \left[ \frac{d}{d t} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \right] \delta x $.

Comment: You say that i don't need to integrate, but if I integrate between $t_1$ and $t_2$ like I did in my previous comment, the term $\left[ \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial  \dot x} \delta x \right]_{t_1}^{t_2} $ was equal to 0 because $\delta x(t_1) = \delta x(t_2) = 0$, but if I don't integrate, why the term $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[ \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} \delta x \right] $ is cancelling this time ?

Comment: Without the integral you can use the argument that two Lagrangians that differ by a total time derivative (as in this case) produce the same equations of motion: as in [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174137/adding-a-total-time-derivative-term-to-the-lagrangian)

Comment: But this argument is valid only if it is a total time derivative of a function that depends only on $x$ and $t$. This is not the case for us because $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} \delta x $ depends also on $\dot x$ ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: That's fair. Integration is probably the right way to go then. The integral would then correspond to the action. The statement that you would be making is that if the action remains invariant under time translation then the Lagrangian must not have explicit time dependence.